# 24V LED strips connected in parallel - How should the data line be connected?

Tags: led, led-strip

i have read around and finally understood how led strips should be run in parallel for my staircase project. However, i have 1 last question that needed an answer.

Please refer to the 1st attached diagram. [image]

According to the diagram, the PSU handles each strip's wattage load separately and the controller does not have to withstand the total wattage load of all the 28m of led strips (400w+).

However, i have a question. How should the data line be connected in this case? Please refer to the 2nd attached picture. [image: 2nd diagram]

It's similar to the led strip that i use except that the one i use is 24V instead of 5V.

I will be connecting the power supply to the extra red + black wire via DC connector.

As for the data line, it will be connected via JST connector. Here's the problem though - it seems to supply power as well through the red wire.

So for the data line, do i remove the red wire and connect only two wires (green & black) from the controller to the led strips?

Because if not, to my limited understanding, wouldn't it mean that the controller and the 4th PSU powering the controller have to sufficiently rated to handle the total wattage of the full 28m of led strips since they are all connected?

Thank you in advance :).

Comment: 400W staircase? Where ? Eiffel Tower?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are correct -- you should leave the ground and data lines (black and green) attached on the JST connector, but disconnect the power line (the red wire).

What would actually probably happen if you left the red wires connected, is that the different power supplies would "fight", and it would probably be harmful to them, depending on their design. Internally to the strip, the two red wires are connected together, and the two black wires are connected together. So if you don't disconnect the red wire from the JST connector, you will just be connecting the different power supplies' outputs directly together.